# How to use COUNT with a GROUP BY on two fields

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, left-join

I am trying to write a query where all buildings will show up for each date, and zeros are listed for the ones that do not exist. Below are an example table and data for my example.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
  `id` int(6) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `buildings` char(3) NOT NULL,
  `date` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `sold` char(1) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `table1` (`id`, `buildings`, `date`, `sold`) VALUES
  ('1', '1', '2019-04-22 07:40:08','X'),
  ('2', '1', '2019-04-22 07:41:15',''),
  ('3', '1', '2019-04-22 07:42:10','X'),
  ('4', '3', '2019-04-22 07:43:50','X'),
  ('5', '1', '2019-04-22 07:44:27',''),
  ('6', '2', '2019-05-21 06:43:17','X'),
  ('7', '2', '2019-05-21 07:36:17',''),
  ('8', '1', '2019-05-21 06:32:22','X'),
  ('9', '3', '2019-05-21 07:43:50',''),
  ('10', '2', '2019-05-21 07:44:27','X');
```

And the SQL query that I am using as of now is listed below. The CONCAT and MID that is used to build the first column are getting the year and week of the year to create a 4 digit code per week.

```
SELECT CONCAT(MID(date,3,2),
           LPAD(WEEK(CONCAT(MID(date,1,4),'-',
           MID(date,6,2),'-',
           MID(date,10,2))),2,0)) AS YearWeek, 
       buildings, 
       COUNT(sold) AS count 
FROM table1 
WHERE sold = 'X' 
GROUP BY CONCAT(MID(date,3,2),
           LPAD(WEEK(CONCAT(MID(date,1,4),'-',
           MID(date,6,2),'-',
           MID(date,10,2))),2,0)),
         buildings
```

My issue with this is I get the data as below

```
YearWeek    buildings   count
1913        1           2
1913        3           1
1917        1           1
1917        2           2
```

When in fact I would like the data to look like the below so I can graph it.

```
YearWeek    buildings   count
1913        1           2
1913        2           0
1913        3           1
1917        1           1
1917        2           2
1917        3           0
```

To achieve this I have tried to do a left join to a subquery
(select distinct building as buildings from table1) but this is not working, and I think it is due to the fact that I am grouping by YearWeek and then building instead of the other way around.'

Any help on this query would be much appreciated!

Comment: You need to cross join a subquery getting the distinct buildings with one that gets the distinct yearweeks, and then left join the table to that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the results you want by taking a `CROSS JOIN` of the distinct `YearWeek` and `buildings` values to get all the possible combinations of each, and then using a `LEFT JOIN` to the table to get the count of each type of `buildings` sold that week. For example:

```
SELECT yw.YearWeek,
       b.buildings,
       COALESCE(SUM(t.sold = 'X'), 0) AS count
FROM (SELECT DISTINCT buildings
      FROM table1) b
CROSS JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT RIGHT(YEARWEEK(date),4) AS YearWeek
            FROM table1) yw
LEFT JOIN table1 t ON t.buildings = b.buildings AND RIGHT(YEARWEEK(t.date),4) = yw.YearWeek
GROUP BY yw.YearWeek, b.buildings
```

Output:

```
YearWeek    buildings   count
1916        1           2
1916        2           0
1916        3           1
1920        1           1
1920        2           2
1920        3           0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2y9SuE2GdHUGmHMPVQnKiD/0)

Note I have used MySQL's inbuilt [`YEARWEEK`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_yearweek) function to simplify the query, you can simply substitute your formula if that is not suitable.

Comment: Thanks! That did it! I was not aware of a cross join, will have to do more looking into that. Unfortunately, I do need my crazy formula as the date I am working with is not this clean, I modified it to try to make the example a little cleaner, but I might have just added confusion.

Comment: @Elmer no worries. `CROSS JOIN` is good for making a table with all combinations of two different variables. It should be easy enough to substitute your formula back in; it's just needed in two places.